# Trying to prevent orientation change on an iPhone 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-4, orientation-changes, shouldautorotate

I have a rotation (orientation change) issue in an iOS app.
The app has several view controllers to navigate.

I want it to be possible to rotate except for iPhone 4 (3.5 inches devices).
On a 3.5 inches device it shoulld always stay in portrait mode.

I am able to prevent direct rotation, that is when inside a view controller, if the user holds the device in portrait mode an them in landscape mode nothing happens. This is exactly what I want.

Problems happen when changing view controller while holding in landscape mode.
In this case the new view controller shows up in landscape mode, and I don't want that.

I tried to use

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
```

returning NO when the device is 3.5 inches but that does not work.

How can I prevent this behavior?

I may need to add one detail:
the 3.5 inches device I am using to test runs iOS version 9.3.5.

I am using Xcode 9.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method [supportedInterfaceOrientations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations).

For example:

**Objective c**

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //return your preferred orientation 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: To be precise and exact I needed to make a slight fix, but you gave me the way to go. I fixed your code so it works if other people look at this post.

Answer (score 0):

You need add this code in **AppDelegate.m**. iPhone 4/ iPhone 4s has screen height of 480 points.

**Objective-C**

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(nullable UIWindow *)window
{
    if(self.window.bounds.size.height > 500) {
        return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

You may also need to enable `Require Full Screen` in Target's `Deployment Info`.

Comment: This does not seem necessary in my case.

Comment: well ok, no issue.